# How can I hide my friends list in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friends

I don't want people to see my friend list when they look at my Facebook account. How can I hide my friends list from people looking at my Facebook account?

When I google for this, I see about 100 different answers, but they all refer to old Facebook versions, with buttons that are no longer there, so I'm trying to find an up to date answer.

Comment: Do you have Timeline or the old profile?

Comment: @mark4o - I have the old profile

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of 10/11/13:

1. Click on your name in top right corner
2. Click “Friends” at the top
   [image]
3. Click the pencil image to “Manage”
   [image]
4. Click “Edit Privacy”
   [image]
5. Modify “Friend List” section by selecting from the drop down menu
   [image]

---

If you have timeline (which I assume you have):

1. Go to your profile
2. Click on your friends list
   [image]
3. Click on **Edit**
   [image]
4. In the popup, click on the icon from the right—in this case the globe, but you might have a different icon, like *friends*
   [image]
5. Select **Only me** (or whatever other option you want)
   [image]

---

Is [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=111110445642532#How-do-I-change-who-can-see-the-people-I%27m-friends-with?) what you are looking for?

1. Go to your profile and click **Edit** in the top right corner
2. From the menu in the left column, click **Friends and Relationships**
3. Go to the **Friends** section and use the [audience selector](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=%20120939471321735) on the right side to control who can see your friends

Comment: I am not talking about my timeline but just my basic profile where it shows list of friends on the left side of the screen

Comment: @leora See the update at the bottom of the answer. (PS: Timeline will become default shortly.)